# "A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator"

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am building an app with the following structure:

```
├── README.md
├── composer.json
├── index.php
└── src
    └── test.php
```

... and my composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "minimum-stability" : "alpha",
    "name" : "patrick/changedetection",
    "description" : "A change detection script for observing additions to web pages",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "patrick\\changedetection\\" : [
                "src/"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run `composer install`, I get

> [InvalidArgumentException]   A non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with
>   a namespace separator.

What do I need to do in order to correctly autoload my test.php file?

===

Edit: This is using Composer version 1.8.4.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've tested your `composer.json` and there is no error given. Have you checked whether the namespace really ends in a double backslash?

Comment: Which version of Composer you're using?

Comment: This is using Composer version 1.8.4 ... and now it works. Strange. Thanks anyway for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have one square brackets more than you need... try to remove them it will be like:

```
{
    "minimum-stability" : "alpha",
    "name" : "patrick/changedetection",
    "description" : "A change detection script for observing additions to web pages",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "autoload" : {
         "psr-4" : {
              "patrick\\changedetection\\" : "src/"
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Actually it should work without this change - you can pass array of directories for namespace prefix: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search for a prefix on single location the no need to add it in.

documentation:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4
That's why your solution would be

```
{
    "minimum-stability" : "alpha",
    "name" : "patrick/changedetection",
    "description" : "A change detection script for observing additions to web pages",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "autoload" : {
         "psr-4" : {
              "patrick\\changedetection\\" : "src/"
         }
     }
}
```

If you need to search for a same prefix in multiple directories, you can specify them as an array as such:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Monolog\\": ["src/", "lib/"] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i had the same problem, i found my solution on the composer's website, and here i paste it:

Under the psr-4 key you define a mapping from namespaces to paths, relative to the package root. When autoloading a class like Foo\Bar\Baz a namespace prefix Foo\ pointing to a directory src/ means that the autoloader will look for a file named src/Bar/Baz.php and include it if present. Note that as opposed to the older PSR-0 style, the prefix (Foo\) is not present in the file path.

Namespace prefixes must end in \ to avoid conflicts between similar prefixes. For example Foo would match classes in the FooBar namespace so the trailing backslashes solve the problem: Foo\ and FooBar\ are distinct.

The PSR-4 references are all combined, during install/update, into a single key => value array which may be found in the generated file vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php.

Example:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Monolog\\": "src/",
        "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

If you need to search for a same prefix in multiple directories, you can specify them as an array as such:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Monolog\\": ["src/", "lib/"] }
}
}
```

If you want to have a fallback directory where any namespace will be looked for, you can use an empty prefix like:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" }
}
}
```

[Composer psr-4  Doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md)